# How to join search patterns in CLiPS pattern.search

Tags: python, nlp, information-extraction

I do pattern matching in text using CLiPS pattern.search (Python 2.7).
I need to extract both phrases that correspond to 'VBN NP' and 'NP TO NP'.
I can do it separately and then join results:

```
from pattern.en import parse,parsetree
from pattern.search import search

text="Published case-control studies have a lot of information about susceptibility to asthma."
sentenceTree = parsetree(text, relations=True, lemmata=True)
matches = []
for match in search("VBN NP",sentenceTree):
    matches.append(match.string)
for match in search("NP TO NP",sentenceTree):
    matches.append(match.string)
print matches
# Output: [u'Published case-control studies', u'susceptibility to asthma']
```

But id I want to join this to one search pattern. If I try this I get no results at all.

```
matches = []
for match in search("VBN NP|NP TO NP",sentenceTree):
    matches.append(match.string)
print matches
#Output: []
```

[Official documentation](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-search) gives no clues for this. I also had tried '{VBN NP}|{NP TO NP}' '[VBN NP]|[NP TO NP]' but without any luck.

**Question is:**
Is it possible to join search patterns in CLiPS pattern.search? 
And if answer is "yes" then how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This pattern worked for me, {VBN NP} *+ {NP TO NP}, along with the match() and group() methods

```
>>> from pattern.search import match
>>> from pattern.en import parsetree


>>> t = parsetree('Published case-control studies have a lot of information about susceptibility to asthma.',relations= True)

>>> m = match('{VBN NP} *+ {NP TO NP}',t)

>>> m.group(0) #matches the complete pattern 
[Word(u'Published/VBN'), Word(u'case-control/NN'), Word(u'studies/NNS'), Word(u'have/VBP'), Word(u'a/DT'), Word(u'lot/NN'), Word(u'of/IN'), Word(u'information/NN'), Word(u'about/IN'), Word(u'susceptibility/NN'), Word(u'to/TO'), Word(u'asthma/NN')]
>>> m.group(1) # matches the first group
[Word(u'Published/VBN'), Word(u'case-control/NN')]
>>> m.group(2) # matches the second group
[Word(u'susceptibility/NN'), Word(u'to/TO'), Word(u'asthma/NN')]
```

finally you can display the result as

```
>>> matches=[]
>>> for i in range(2):
...     matches.append(m.group(i+1).string)
... 
>>> matches
[u'Published case-control', u'susceptibility to asthma']
```

Comment: It was an example. Word order may be different or only one type of pattern will occurr in sentence...or more than two. and it will fail.